# Getting undefined for a key that exists

Tags: javascript

I am very new to node.js but I don't think this should be happening:

```
const snekfetch = require('snekfetch');
const auth = require('../auth.json');
const totext = require('html-to-text');

exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    const content = args.join(" ");
    const tagged = args[0];

    snekfetch.get("http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search?pagesize=1&order=desc&sort=votes&tagged="+tagged+"&intitle="+content+"&site=stackoverflow&key=censored")
    .then(r => console.log(r["body"]["items"]["accepted_answer_id"]));
    /*
    var text = htmlToText.fromString(bodyofsnek, {
        wordwrap: 130
    });
    */
}
```

This prints out undefined.
removing the ["accepted_answer_id"] gives me this object:

```
[{"tags":["javascript","object","undefined"],"owner":{"reputation":60056,"user_id":797,"user_type":"registered","accept_rate":68,"profile_image":"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/aef85130bf44caa9b4de0a3153e758f2?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG","display_name":"Matt Sheppard","link":"https://stackoverflow.com/users/797/matt-sheppard"},"is_answered":true,"view_count":857526,"protected_date":1335343521,"accepted_answer_id":416327,"answer_count":37,"score":2180,"last_activity_date":1504076618,"creation_date":1219735508,"last_edit_date":1447031189,"question_id":27509,"link":"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property","title":"Detecting an undefined object property"}]
```

And I can see accepted_answer_id in there with its value as 416327.
So why is it returning undefined?

Comment: items is an array. You need to reference it with an index value, not a key name.

Comment: @user2263572 thanks that worked. Why not post that as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

items is an array. You need to reference it with an index value, not a key name.

For example:

```
r["body"]["items"][0]
```